# How to remove odoo from this browser tab?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

[image]

How to remove odoo from Assetcatg-Odoo tab .Any procedure to do it is appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code.

```
    <template id="remove_odoo.web_layout" inherit_id="web.layout">
       <xpath expr="//title" position="replace"></xpath>
    </template>
```

if You want to create new module create new module name it remove_odoo or you can directly modify from `addons/web/views/webclient_templates.xml` and edit `<title>` tag inside the `<template id="web.layout" name="Web layout">`

Comment: i have renamed with other word but its not changed to it

Comment: Did you restart server with update .? did you create new module.? try after removing cookies also. and still doesnt work post your code.

Comment: yeah i just changed the name at there in .xml file but its not done

Comment: okay so you have change in main source code so you need to restart your server by updating web module like -d <dbname> -u web

Comment: other changes are done like powered by odoo has been changed to other name its working fine only above image part is left so

Answer (score 3):

I got it. I have changed at 
`addons/web/static/src/js/chrome.js`:

`this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp":  "Odoo"});` to `this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "PTPL"});`

[image]

```
instance.web.WebClient = instance.web.Client.extend({
    init: function(parent, client_options) {
        this._super(parent);
        if (client_options) {
            _.extend(this.client_options, client_options);
        }
        this._current_state = null;
        this.menu_dm = new instance.web.DropMisordered();
        this.action_mutex = new $.Mutex();
        #this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "Odoo"});
        this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "PTPL"});

    },
```

Comment: in Odoo 10 the file to edit is located here 
                          
            addons\web\static\src\js\abstract_web_client.js